# How to replace the UITabBar with a UIToolbar on iOS 11?

Tags: ios, uitabbar, uitoolbar

I'm trying to develop something similar to the photos app. When the user switches to edit mode I would like to hide the UITabBar and replace it with a UIToolBar. Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcEEv.jpg

I have a UIViewController embedded in a UINavigationController. The UINavigationController is embedded in a UITabBarController. I added some UIBarButtonItems to the UIViewController.

I tried the following in my UIViewController:

`tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: false)`

Unfortunately the UIToolBar is not adjusting its position: https://i.stack.imgur.com/51qHz.jpg

I also tried to use a custom UIToolbar which is working nicely on all devices but the iPhone X. On the iPhone X its displayed below the home button.

Comment: Are you pushing to a new VC? Or are you just trying to hide the TabBar and show your ToolBar?

Comment: No I only want to hide the TabBar and show the ToolBar.

Comment: Add UIToolBar over the UITabBar using leading, top, trailing and height constraints. hide/show UIToolBar with edit mode.

Comment: This is working but it's looking a little bit weird on the iPhone X. The toolbar items are centered and are not placed like regular items in a UIToolBar.